# Testing a promise that's expected to fail using Jest

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, jestjs

I am trying to use Jest to test a function that returns a promise.

The function manyUrls expects an array of URLs containing JSON data to be passed. The contents of these URLs are fetched and returned in an array.
I am testing the case where a valid URL string is passed. This throws a TypeError as expected, but I'm having trouble using promises to write a test for that (async/await works fine)

```js
//index.js
const manyUrls = (urls) => {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)))
    .then(responses =>
      Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()))
    ).then(texts => {
      return Promise.resolve(texts)
    }).catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
} 

//index.test.js
const manyUrls = require("./index")
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'


test('Expect TypeError if a single string is passed', () => {
  // expect.assertions(1);
  // try {
  //   await manyUrls(url);
  // } catch (e) {
  //   expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
  // }


  return manyUrls(url).catch(e =>
    expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError)
  )
})
```

I have left commented out the bit of code that successfully passes that test case using async/await (if I add async to the callback) but I am trying to make this work with promises. I have followed the documentation on https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous but can't seem to get that test to pass. Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't include images of text. Show _that text_, using normal code markup. As for your code: if `urls` can be null, update your function with an `if (!urls) { return Promise.reject(new Error(...)); } ...`, because your code should be able to deal with that. Tests are there to verify the code works, especially when hitting edge cases. You found an edge case. So fix your code first.

Comment: I have also added text. I know my function could include input checking but the point of my question is about testing promises. As you can see, a TypeError is thrown and my test is expecting an instance of TypeError but the test case still fails...

Comment: As a new user to Stackoverflow: please follow [the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) like everyone else has to. Your image is an image _of text_, show that text instead, marked up as code. And definitely form a [mcve] here, primarily to force yourself to find the true problem (and then if, once you've reduced things down to the bare minimum and you still have this problem, _that code_ lets others help you figure things out much, much better).

Comment: I have removed the image and reformulated my question. Please let me know if that's still not ok.

Comment: And now remember to show the _error_ as normal text, too. My comments were not about "removing the image", it's about [not using images when you're showing text](/help/how-to-ask): copy-paste the actual text, and put it in a code block so it's monospace formatted. Also note that your code is _not_ a runnable snippet, it's node/jest code, so don't put it in runnable tags, just use regular code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return manyUrls(url)...` code would work just fine if your `manyUrls` function returned a Promise - but it *doesn't* when the `urls` parameter is not an Array.

There is a big difference between a function that returns a Promise which rejects with an Error and a function which throws an Error. By using `return` in your test, you are telling Jest that your function is the former, when in actuality your function is the latter.

In `manyUrls`, the first line, `return Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)))` tries to call `urls.maps` but throws an Error when `urls` is not an Array (as in the test case). In throwing the Error, no Promise is returned.

Your try/catch implementation works because it catches the Error that `manyUrls` is throwing. If you want the `return` implementation to work, then `manyUrls` must return a Promise that rejects.

The simplest way to update `manyUrls` to *always* return a Promise would be to add the `async` keyword - as in `const manyUrls = async (urls) => {`. By making it an async function, any Errors thrown from `manyUrls` will automatically be turned into the rejection value of the returned Promise. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value